# With Entity Framework Is it possible to create an entity that is not mapped on a table of my database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Entity Framework : Is it possible to create an entity that is not mapped on a table of my database?

Comment: Because my model needs objets that i don't want to persist in database but should exist in memory.

Comment: Then it's just a regular (*in-memory*) class - not an entity....

Comment: In this case I don't see the advantages of the EF. My Business Model is composed by objetc I need to persists and others. I don't want to split my Business Model in two parts (namespace).

Comment: Your EF entity classes and your other classes can be in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Entity Framework is really about auto-generating classes that have all the guts to be easily used in Web Services and connected to Databases. If you don't need those capabilities of EF, then all you are really doing is using a UI to make your Entity Classes, rather than just coding them out by hand. It's certainly possible, but you don't gain much by doing so and end up with a lot of auto-generated bloat in your code base.

Indeed, since EF does it "a certain way" you lose some flexibility that is otherwise available to you by defining your own Entity Classes in source.

Answer (score 3):

In such case it is not an entity but just a class = create normal class file and you are done. That class cannot be part of your entity model (EDMX) or code first mapping because it is not related to persistence (and EF).

Comment: From the definition of an Entity it's an Entity. Entity doesn't mean persistance in a relational database. (Except for Microsoft perhaps)

Comment: But it is still just your own class and you can use it as any other class. It just cannot be declared in your entity model / mapping and cannot be autogenerated by EF tools.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NotMapped] attribute and still have it tracked within DbContext.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Class in the EF or create a class in seperate class `ClassName.cs` and use it as your model.

Better to Use the Second option, since i will be more clear and if EF grows large, it will be hard to find your class from there and modify.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "Complex type" for that.